# Why imgs don't open on click after "id" changes?

Tags: modal-dialog

I changed images "id" and now they aren't clickable, before I make these changes just first image was clickable and opens on click. Where is "mistake"?

```
<img id="myImg74" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0414/1626/1789/files/WhatsApp_Image_2020-10-26_at_13.22.37_600x600.jpg?v=1603779634" alt="" width="300" height="300">
<img id="myImg75" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0414/1626/1789/files/WhatsApp_Image_2020-10-26_at_13.22.38_600x600.jpg?v=1603779652" alt="" width="300" height="300">

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close">&times;</span>
  <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
  <div id="caption"></div>
</div>
<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
    var arr = ["myImg0","myImg1","myImg2", "myImg3", "myImg4", "myImg5", "myImg6", 
    "myImg7", "myImg8", "myImg9", "myImg10", "myImg11", "myImg12", "myImg13", 
    "myImg14", "myImg15", "myImg16", "myImg17", "myImg18", "myImg19", "myImg20", "myImg21", "myImg22", "myImg23", "myImg24", "myImg25", "myImg26", "myImg27", "myImg28", "myImg29", "myImg30", "myImg31", "myImg32", "myImg33", "myImg34", "myImg35", "myImg36", "myImg37", "myImg38", "myImg39", "myImg40", "myImg41", "myImg42", "myImg43", "myImg44", "myImg45", "myImg46", "myImg47", "myImg48", "myImg49", "myImg50", "myImg51", "myImg52", "myImg53", "myImg54", "myImg55", "myImg56", "myImg57", "myImg58", "myImg59", "myImg60", "myImg61", "myImg62", "myImg63", "myImg64", "myImg65", "myImg66", "myImg67", "myImg68", "myImg69", "myImg70", "myImg71", "myImg72", "myImg73", "myImg74", "myImg75"];
    for(var i=0;i< arr.length;i++)
// Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
var img = document.getElementById(arr[i]);
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
img.onclick = function(){
  modal.style.display = "block";
  modalImg.src = this.src;
  captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() { 
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED!!!**

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <span class="close" onclick="document.getElementById('myModal').style.display='none'">&times;</span>
  
  <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
  
  <div id="caption"></div>
</div>
<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
var img = $('.myImg');
var modalImg = $("#img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
$('.myImg').click(function(){
    modal.style.display = "block";
    var newSrc = this.src;
    modalImg.attr('src', newSrc);
    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
});

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

***HEAD!!!***

```
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}

.myImg {
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.myImg:hover {opacity: 0.7;}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content (Image) */
.modal-content {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
}

/* Caption of Modal Image (Image Text) - Same Width as the Image */
#caption {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    height: 150px;
}

/* Add Animation - Zoom in the Modal */
.modal-content, #caption {
    -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
    animation-name: zoom;
    animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
    from {-webkit-transform:scale(0)}
    to {-webkit-transform:scale(1)}
}

@keyframes zoom {
    from {transform:scale(0)}
    to {transform:scale(1)}
}
.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 35px;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #bbb;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
</head>   ~~~
```